# Interface reference problems in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

i'm trying to learn interfaces, and got stuck on this problem..

i have 3 libraries..

1. **calculateLibrary**
    arguments.cs ,
    calculator.cs ,
    calculatorMain.cs ,
    commandTypes.cs ,
    inputParser.cs ,
    setInput.cs
2. **InterfacesLibrary**
    Iarguments.cs ,
    Icalculator.cs ,
    IcalculatorMain.cs ,
    IinputParser.cs ,
    IsetInput.cs
3. **typescript(web)**
    index.aspx

so my problem is some of my interfaces methods is not working, or it says "the type or namespace name 'commandTypes cound not be found(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

the commandTypes in my IinputParser is what the error is pointing.

code for my interface

```
    namespace calculateLibrary
{
    public interface IinputParser
    {
        commandTypes parseCommand(string command);
    }
}
```

and code for the method that inherits the interface

```
    namespace calculateLibrary
{
    public class inputParser : IinputParser
    {
        public commandTypes parseCommand(string command)
        {
            return ((commandTypes)Enum.Parse(typeof(commandTypes), command));

        }
    }
}
```

this is the code for my commandType class

```
namespace calculateLibrary
{
    public enum commandTypes
    {
        add,
        sub,
        mul,
        div
    }
}
```

i think the problem is not about reference..because some of my Interfaces is working fine..i mean there is no error.. i saw some related post but those didn't help me.

thanks.

Comment: It's not possible. As you said the `InterfacesLibrary` library uses types in `calculateLibrary` library (`IinputParser` uses `commandTypes`), at the same time `calculateLibrary` library uses types in `InterfacesLibrary` library (`inputParser` uses `IinputParser`), Visual Studio won't allow you to do this because it causes a circular dependency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since both `IinputParser` and `inputParser` need to use `commandTypes`, I would suggest moving `commandTypes.cs` to `InterfacesLibrary` project to avoid circular reference. The namespace needs to be changed as well. Here's what the code of `commandTypes` should look like after being moved to `InterfacesLibrary` project:

```
namespace InterfacesLibrary
{
    public enum commandTypes
    {
        add,
        sub,
        mul,
        div
    }
}
```

The code of `IinputParser` should have `InterfacesLibrary` as the namespace

```
namespace InterfacesLibrary
{
    public interface IinputParser
    {
        commandTypes parseCommand(string command);
    }
}
```

and here's the code of `inputParser` class:

```
using InterfacesLibrary;

namespace calculateLibrary
{
    public class inputParser : IinputParser
    {
        public commandTypes parseCommand(string command)
        {
            return ((commandTypes)Enum.Parse(typeof(commandTypes), command));

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem is Circular Reference as you have declared `commandTypes` in your **CalculateLibrary** and use it in `IinputParser` Interface in `public commandTypes parseCommand(string command)` which is in **InterfaceLibrary**, then your want to reference **InterfaceLibrary** from **CalculateLibrary**.

*CommandTypes (CalculateLibrary) -> IinputParser (InterfaceLibrary) -> inputParser (CalculateLibrary)*

you should either put these classes used by your Interfaces in **InterfaceLibrary**, or declare them in a lower level library as somthing like Core and then reference it from both **InterfaceLibrary** and **CalculateLibrary**